# C++/XAML UWP NuGet packages with managed dependencies

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Let's start with a C++/CX UWP project from scratch where i need a NuGet packages who use managed dependencies (like Newtonsoft.Json). This is actually impossible to install this because my project uses native C++ (not C#).

I red this post in github for my searchs : https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6146

But i wondering if there exists a solution to get around or plan in the future ?

Comment: What you should do is to vote up [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5292). Whether there is a plan for this should depend on the official site, not SO. Please keep following up with the same issue on the official site.

Answer (score 1):

C++ cannot call C# (or any other managed code) directly in UWP. (Desktop C++ has C++/CLI, aka "Managed C++", but that is not available for UWP). The easiest way to call managed code from C++ is to create a WinRT component with the managed code and then reference it from your C++ code.